# Change values of IPrincipal on the fly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom role manager in my mvc site, and, I need to change some values in Current User context, to make this, I tried this:

```
    public JsonResult AlteraAsConfiguracoes(int id)
    {
        var empresa = Code.DataAccess.Repository.EmpresaDataRepository.GetAllEmpresasComboBox().empresasAdmin[id];
        HttpContext.User.ToCustomPrincipal().NomeDaEmpresa = empresa.Nome;
        HttpContext.User.ToCustomPrincipal().EmpresaId = empresa.EmpresaAdminId;
        return Json(new { sucesso = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My method in global.asax to register the user is that:

```
   protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);
            CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
            newUser.UserId = serializeModel.UserId;
            newUser.EmpresaId = serializeModel.EmpresaId;
            newUser.Nome = serializeModel.Nome;
            newUser.SobreNome = serializeModel.SobreNome;
            newUser.roles = serializeModel.roles;
            newUser.NomeDaEmpresa = serializeModel.NomeDaEmpresa;

            HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
        }
    }
```

But, not work...

How I can make this ?

Ps. If is necessary more code of my login system, just ask what I put here.